# Xamarin IOS: How to handle notification tap when the app is not in the background?(killed state)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I have implemented push notification on my xamarin forms project(chat application) using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Notification is receiving in all the states and when tapping the notification I need to show the corresponding message listing page.

**Notification tapping is working when the app is in the foreground and background modes. But when the app is not present in the background(killed state), tapping is not working.** Using `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` I am handling the notification tap when the app is in the background state. Using `WillPresentNotification` and `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` I am showing the notification and handling the notification tap in foreground mode. Codes added below:

```
 //Notification tapping when the app is in background mode.
 public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            HandleMessage(userInfo);

            // Print full message.
            LogInformation(nameof(DidReceiveRemoteNotification), userInfo);

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);

            var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<webContentList>>(userInfo[new NSString("webContentList")] as NSString);
            Console.WriteLine($"myData received: {myData}");
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState.Equals(UIApplicationState.Active))
            {
                //App is in foreground, no action
            }
            else
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, List<webContentList>>(this, "messagedata", myData);
            }
        }

        //Showing the notification when the app is in the foreground mode.
       [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
        public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification,
Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
        {
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
        }

        //Notification tapping when the app is in the foreground mode.
[Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
            public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action
            completionHandler)
            {
                completionHandler();
                NSDictionary userInfo = response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;
                var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<webContentList>>(userInfo[new NSString("webContentList")] as NSString);
                Console.WriteLine($"myData received: {myData}");
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, List<webContentList>>(this, "messagedata", myData);
            }
```

**FinishedLaunching**

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            LoadApplication(new App());

            #region Push Notification            
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

            // Register your app for remote notifications.
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // iOS 10 or later
                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

                // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
                //Messaging.SharedInstance.RemoteMessageDelegate = this;
            }
            else
            {
                // iOS 9 or before
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
            Messaging.SharedInstance.ShouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
            #endregion

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

**My notification body:** `webContentList` is my model data.

```
{
 "to" : "dmtfiSvBBM0:APA91bFnHkamMSYgxPuiSfdvKnU8hD_mOqrWijnENNgXVSkSgo1ILH3-uKVCU7Ez2PXXOhtDoobIyKBf5UshVfTmvjSqHgXMRTsqguKCSTjIfGnXrVP-_cNFq2sisshZO-BcfkwKTl-I",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is body",
     "title": "Tech Team",
     "priority":"high",
     "content_available":true
 },
 "data" : {
    "webContentList": [
        {
            "webContentDefinitionId": 818084,
            "pageTitle": "CCD Grade 3-4",
            "pageKwd": "CCD Grade 3-4",
            "pageDesc": "CCD Grade 3-4",
            "siteId": 45,
            "pageCreatedTime": 1555145959428,
            "pageUpdatedDate": 1555927274279,
            "modifier": {
                "userId": 12944,
                "applicationId": 32,
                "username": "robert.downey",
                "email": "robert@master-mail.net",
                "firstName": "Robert",
                "lastName": "Downey"
            },
            "creator": {
                "userId": 12944,
                "applicationId": 32,
                "username": "robert.downey",
                "email": "robert@master-mail.net",
                "firstName": "Robert",
                "lastName": "Downey"
            }
        }
        ]
 },
  "ttl": 3600
}
```

**Issue**

When the app is in the killed state only the home page is loading, not showing the message listing page. But before showing the home page in the UI, the message listing show progress(acr userdialogs) is also present in the UI. So I think `LoadApplication(new App());` in `FinishedLaunching` is working after the notification tap function when the app is in the killed state. So how I can stop the execution of the normal app launching code and show the message listing page when the app is in the killed state?

**Update**

Tried like below. Initial launching was fine but crashing when launching via notification tap.

```
  LoadApplication(new App());

        if (options != null)
        {
            var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<webContentList>>(options[new NSString("webContentList")] as NSString);
            if(myData != null)
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, List<webContentList>>(this, "messagedata", myData);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hope it helps you, if anything else please ping here.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the data to Forms Project by extending App constructor.

> AppDelegate in iOS

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {

        var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<webContentList>>(options[new NSString("webContentList")] as NSString);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App(myData));

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

> App in Forms

```
public App(List<webContentList> list)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // handle the logic 
    }
```

## Update

```
LoadApplication(new App());
MessagingCenter.Send<object, List<webContentList>>(this, "messagedata", myData);
```

Comment: In this case, how can I handle the normal launching of the app?

Comment: Load the list page here .

Comment: Is it possible to use `MessagingCenter` instead of passing via arguments to App.xaml.cs? Because I have already used `MessagingCenter` in foreground and background modes.

Comment: If myData is null, it means app is launching normally, and if myData id not null it means app is launching via notification tap, right?

Comment: Try to send MessagingCenter afterLoadApplication(new App());

Comment: Can you please see the question, I have added an update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196459/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-lucas-zhang-msft).